# Database update question

Tags: sql, mysql, odbc

I'm using MySql and am pretty new to it.

I have a table which stores 5 measurements every X seconds (configurable, but always the same fore each test run)

I am taking 4 measurements over serial port, but the other must be measured manually.

I write a new row, with timestamp, every time I measure at the 4 serial ports (every X seconds), which means that value of the manual measurement is written as its value last time it was measured.

Now, suppose the user takes a sample at presciently 10:000:00 and goes to manually analayze and comes back 2 minutes later to enter the value into my program... I have already written the previous value for the period 10:00:: to 10:02:00 and I have to go back and update them to the value just entered.

Is there one simple statement that will do that?  just lock the table or dataset, find all rows between two timestamps and update one column to the new value, then unlock?

Comment: We're not telepathic -- if you have business rules, you need to explain them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      UPDATE Measurements
         SET ManualMeasurement = 'someNumber'
       WHERE TimeTaken Between 'startTime' AND 'endTime'
```

is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: +1 and the answer. That is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't tried it, but it looks good.  Thanks

Comment: My pleasure!  Glad to be of help.

Comment: My pleasure to give another +1    ;-)

Comment: p.s it seems that the keyword TABLE is not required (gave an error), but without it, it works;